# Addthis Email Share onClick popup modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

I had this working initially. But now its not. Here is my code.

```
<a class="addthis_button_email">
    <div class="text-center pointer email padding-10 col-lg-6 col-ms-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o margin-right-6"></i> Email
   </div>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5614123fb956b74f"></script>
```

I don't know what has gone wrong, but what I want is **When we click on share Email button it should open in a popup modal instead of new tab.**

If anyone have done this before or have any reference material for getting this done will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue with Addthis, where a bunch of websites we were using this feature suddenly started opening new windows instead of modal.

So I've contacted Addthis support and they came back with:

"Its expected behaviors. It's a new change that we recently implemented in the email App service."

At this point, I don't think we can do anything to make it work in modal as before.

Comment: Thanks Wilfrid Li I too just got the mail from addthis.